# How does the break clause respond in this examples?

Tags: java, loops, break

How does the `break` clause work?

I understand if I have a `break` inside a loop, the loop will terminate it's execution. For example:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    break;
}
```

But would it work if the `break` clause it's inside of a loop but also inside of a `if`or an `else`? For example:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (i==7) {   
       //code
       break;
       //code
    }
}
```

Will the `break` clause make the `for` loop end or just will skip the code next to it on the `if` clause and continue iterating?

What if the `break` clause it's inside a loop inside of a loop? Would it end the execution of both loops or just the nearest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from JLS (highlighted 2 parts you are struggling with): "A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to **the innermost enclosing** (1) **`switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement** (2) of the immediately enclosing method or initializer; this statement, which is called the break target, then immediately completes normally."

Comment: [JLS 14.15. The break Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A break statement will always exit only the inner loop. If-statements are not counted as those. If you need to break multiple loops at once you can use tags:

```java
A: while (true) {
    B: while (true) {
         break A;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'break' statement always breaks the loop. If you would like to skip an iteration at a specific index, you can use the 'continue' keyword:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
if (i==7) {   
   //code
   continue;
   //second part of code
}
```

}

What this code will do is, if i == 7, it will run the //code part and when it reaches the continue statement, it will immediately skip the //second part of code and move to the next iteration i = 8. If you have multiple nested loops, a break statement will break only the loop on which it is applied. However, if a parent loop is broken, the child (nested) loop will automatically break too.

```
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
      if(j==3){
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

This code will only break the inner loop whenever j is equal to 3. Bear in mind tho, since the second loop is nested, even when it breaks, it will run again when the parent loop goes to its next index.

Answer (score 1):

the `break` causes a jump to the end of the loop, see below:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (i==7) {   
       // code here will be executed
       break;
       // code here will not be executed
    }
} // break statement is like a goto to this line
```

a `break` will always only affect one loop, the most inner loop it is inside

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (i==7) {   
       //code A
       break;
       //code B
    }
}
```

This will run loop 8 times and will break the whole loop on `i=7`. Also, `code B` after `break` statement will be unreachable so it makes no sense to write it in this case.